# Is there any online Apache Hive 0.14 editor with sample db with tables?

Tags: hive

I would like to practice Hive 14 sql queries. 
Is there any **online**  Apache Hive 0.14 editor with sample db with tables?

Answer (score 11):

You can try this (Not sure of Hive version though): [Hue](http://demo.gethue.com/)

Answer (score 3):

`http://demo.gethue.com/hue/editor/?type=hiv`

As pointed by @Venkat above url with user/password as demo/demo can be accessed